# Запрос по 2 полям одной таблицы SQLite (по очереди)

Tags: sqlite

Есть таблица, в ней - много полей.

Хочу выбрать все поля, где `поле_имени` совпадает с моим текстом, в этом же запросе хочу вытащить все поля, где `поле_описания` совпадает этим же текстом.

Как это сделать? Или хотя бы покажите, в какую сторону копать =)

Сами запросы:

```
SELECT * FROM table_goods WHERE name LIKE '%искомый_текст%'
SELECT * FROM table_goods WHERE descr LIKE '%искомый_текст%'
```

Мне нужно просто, чтобы результат этих запросов был общий, но чтобы 1я половина результата была с совпадением в имени, а 2я половина с совпадением  в описании.

Например,

```
id "1", name "мандарин", descr "с марковкой хорошо"
id "2", name "марковка", descr "описание"
id "3", name "огурцы-1", descr "сочетается с молоком"
id "4", name "помидоры", descr "с мясом хорошо сочетается"
id "5", name "марковный_сок", descr "описание"
```

Выполняем запрос LIKE '%марков%' сначала по имени потом по описанию и в результате хотим получить:

```
id "2", name "марковка", descr "описание"
id "5", name "марковный_сок", descr "описание"
id "1", name "мандарин", descr "с марковкой хорошо"
```

Отобразил сначала результаты по имени, потом по описанию.

Помогите сделать одним запросом, пожалуйста.

Comment: См. оператор `UNION`.

Comment: @Yaant, сейчас посмотрю

Comment: UNION нежелателен - это безусловная дополнительная и не очень нужная сортировка.

Comment: @Akina Ну, после `LIKE %...%` оверхедом на сортировку можно практически пренебречь. :) А если некритично дублирование записей, у которых искомый текст есть одновременно и в названии и в описании, то и вовсе можно использовать `UNION ALL`

Comment: Это верно, но с оглядкой на объём данных. Всё-таки Like работает с одним полем, а сортировка будет работать со всей записью. Опять же Like можно заставить выполнять скан индекса, если таковой есть. Так что может оказаться, что оверхед и не такой и объёмный. Остальное - см. коммент к посту **Nikolay Baranenko**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_goods 
WHERE name  LIKE '%искомый_текст%'
   OR descr LIKE '%искомый_текст%'
-- ORDER BY (name LIKE '%искомый_текст%') DESC
```

Comment: а DESC для чего?

Comment: @zayn1991 для сортировки данных в порядке убывания

Comment: @Akina, проверил, работает отлично)

Comment: @zayn1991 Если условие истинно, сравнение даёт True, которое приводится к числовому 1, а если нет, то False, которое 0. Т.к. нам нужно сперва совпадение по name - сперва нужны 1, а потом 0, потому и DESC.

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю, такой запрос решит данную задачу:

```
SELECT * FROM table_goods WHERE name LIKE '%марков%' OR descr LIKE '%марков%'
  ORDER BY (CASE WHEN name LIKE '%марков%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
```

Comment: "CASE WHEN THEN 1 ELSE 2 END" что это? никогда не сталкивался

Comment: Это сортировка по условию. Позволяет осуществлять более сложную сортировку. Например, сначала выводить результаты, где `name = искомый_текст`, следом те, в которых `name LIKE %искомый_текст%`, а потом уже те, в которых `descr LIKE %искомый_текст%`:
`ODER BY (CASE WHEN name = 'марковка' THEN 1 WHEN name LIKE '%марковка%' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END)`

Comment: работает, но эти команды для меня в новинку, если надо будет редактировать - с этими командами с моим уровнем я не смогу работать. У тебя и у пользователя "Akina" одна и та же реализация?

Comment: Да, это фактически одна и та же реализация. Просто в этом варианте добавляется ещё одно вычисление - в данном случае ненужное.

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так

```
SELECT id, name, descr FROM table_goods WHERE name LIKE '%искомый_текст%'
UNION
SELECT id, name, descr FROM table_goods WHERE descr LIKE '%искомый_текст%'
```

Comment: "UNION нежелателен - это безусловная дополнительная и не очень нужная сортировка. – Akina"

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но у меня будет габаритная таблица, поэтому мне не подойдет, итераций много выйдет чтоб записи не дублировались, а я на андроид реализую

Comment: Разумнее UNION ALL, и во второй запрос добавить AND NOT (name LIKE '%искомый_текст%'). Эффект тот же, но сортировка заменится дополнительным отбором, что быстрее и дешевле. А если ещё стрельнёт index merge...